# How to call a method when values has been entered in text box

Tags: objective-c, textbox

In my app, i have a text box and handheld scanner. when i scanned something, the barcode values comes in text box. I don't need any special code to get the bar code value inside the text box. Till here i am fine. But now when i have a value in textbox , i want to call a method which will further do some changes in Core data. I have the code to make changes into core data for the row with value = value in text box.

But i don't know how to call this method or how do i know that values been entered in text box and i can call the method.

Please help me in doing that.

Comment: Find out when the scanner has finished by if(code for scanner finishing) { [self updateCoreData];} inside the updateCoreData method, do your core data update stuff, and that should be all you need to do. Hope that helps :)

Comment: This is problem that i don't know when the value is entered in textfield from scanner. I want to call updateCoreData method as soon as value is entered into textbox. But i don't know how to check if value is entered in textbox

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes handheld device add return character to the end and if yours do that add delegate to the text field

```
self.textField.delegate = self;
```

and see is that method called:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidEndEditing method called");
}
```

If this method is not called add notification to the text field which will be called when the text changed:

```
[self.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and add method which will be called:

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidChange method called");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use delegate's `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` instead of notifications, if `-textFieldDidEndEditing:` does not work?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad this method is created to for do something else. You should use it if you don't want to change the text. So I would rather use notification but it's my personal choice.

Comment: I do not think so: This method *can* reject the content. Notifications observes can never by design. This is not intended, but simply not possible by design.  (You can have many notification observers. Which one should take the decision?) The real (intended) difference is: Notification observers are informed via broadcast, delegates are specific to an object. In this case he wants to react in a specific way to an input of an object -> delegate.

Comment: To give an example: If he would have many (>1) independent parts in this software that reacts on an input, notifications would be the better choice. In both cases (+textFieldDidEndEditing).

Comment: If i use notification, then textFieldDidChange method is called for number of item equal to the characters in the textfield. I want to call method only for once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an IBOutlet variable and link it to your textbox.

```
@interface YourClassOrController
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *myTextField;
}
...
@end
```

In interface Builder, you need to Ctrl-Drag to link your textfield to your variable.

Finally in your code you use

```
NSString code = [myTextField stringValue];
```